# Pull-Down gesture not working with uipageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem with the pull-down gesture that is not working. I'm presenting an `UIPageViewController` and each pages is a `UIViewController` containing an `UITableView`. when the transition style is set to `pageCurl` there is not problem with the pull-down gesture to dismiss but when the transition style is set to `scroll`, I can't dismiss the view. Only the `UITableView` is scrolling even when at the top

```
final class HistoryReceiptContainerViewController: UIPageViewController {

    private let viewModel: HistoryReceiptContainerViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: HistoryReceiptContainerViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setViewControllers([receiptViewController(for: HistoryReceiptViewModel(historyId: "1234", source: "", context: nil, contextId: nil))], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    private func receiptViewController(for viewModel: HistoryReceiptViewModel) -> HistoryReceiptViewController {
        let vc = HistoryReceiptViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        return vc
    }
}
```

And the code to present the view

```
present(HistoryReceiptContainerViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
```

Do you have any solutions for that kind of problem ?

Thank you in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYaXj.jpg

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Have you maybe already found a solution in the mean time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example implementation to fix dismissing a `UIPageViewController` with transitionStyle .scroll by adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and some custom gesture recognizer handling. It will work when pushing the `UIPageViewController` on a navigation stack as well as when presenting it modally.

```
class DemoPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
 
    var presentedModally = false

    init(presentedModally: Bool = false) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, //if you would use .pageCurl dismissing works
                   navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
                   options: nil)
        self.presentedModally = presentedModally
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpPanGestureForDismissingSelf()
    }

    // MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard let navigationController = navigationController, navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer == gestureRecognizer else {
            return true
        }
        return navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return !presentedModally
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return presentedModally
    }

    private func setUpPanGestureForDismissingSelf() {
        guard presentedModally else { return }
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                          action: #selector(handlePanGesture(sender:)))
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func handlePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let dragVelocity = sender.velocity(in: view)
        if dragVelocity.y >= 1300 {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```